# How can I read 30MB text file using php script?

Tags: php, file, loops, text

Hi I do have a text file with size of upto 30MB I would like to read this file using PHP loop script

```
$lines = file('data.txt');

//loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line) { \\some function }
```

Is there any way? I want open it for reading php doesnt allow me to open a 30MB file.

Comment: What do you want to do with the file?

Comment: I want read line by line then process data using infromation from text file then insert into MySQl database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could read it line by line like this:

```
$file = fopen("data.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($file)) {
  // do what you need to do with it - just echoing it out for this example
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: See my problem is php doesnt allow me to open 30mb file.

Comment: What does it say when you try to do what I posted?

Comment: @leon comments like that aren't going to get you any help.  Its not working doesn't allow anyone to help you.  As the above posters said, you have to tell us what it says.  What kind of error message are you getting when you try to run that code?

Comment: I turned off error messages hence It wasnt showing but a blank page. I initially tested but not realized that error message was disabled and that leads to my first comment. later I found closing bracket missing from then things were working fine....

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line using:

```
 $handle = fopen ( "data.txt", "r" );

 while ( ( $buffer = fgets ( $handle, 4096 ) ) !== false ) {
    // your function on line;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing warnings? (@)

Comment: sorry by bad habbit - removed

Answer (score 0):

If it is suitable for you to read the file piece-by-piece you can try something like this

```
$fd = fopen("fileName", "r");
while (!feof($fd)) {
$buffer = fread($fd, 16384); //You can change the size of the buffer according to the memory you can youse
//Process here the buffer, piece by piece
}
fclose($fd);
```